# Need help identifying or locating pieces - 4-stud T-shaped plates

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I'm trying to find plates to build a baseball mascot with my kids. I can't find the actual set anywhere (it's actually a FOCO BRXLZ brand set), so I am trying to piecemeal the set. I'm not concerned with it being Lego brand, so long as the pieces will all work together to create the end product.

I've attached a picture from the instructions showing what I need in quantity and color. These are the only plates I can't find on the Lego Pick a Brick shop:

[image: 4-stud T-shaped plates]

Answer (score 7):

I can't speak for other brands, but I'm sure that there is no such LEGO element.

This would be a plate, but [the Bricklink category](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=26) has nothing exactly like this design.

The closest would be the [Plate 2 x 2 Corner](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2420#T=C) or [Plate 3 x 3 Cross](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15397#T=C), but the first requires an additional plate, which could prove unfeasible due to the missing structural bonds, and the latter has an extra plate (which could be cut away if needed, even though that would be considered a bad choice by many).

---

Edit

As jpa noted below, if these parts should serve as structural support, the required strength could be achieved by attaching a [Plate 1 X 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3623) and a [Plate 1 X 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3024) together by their sides. These LEGO bricks are made of ABS, therefore the suitable binding agents would be acetone, cyanoacrylate (superglue), or epoxy.

Comment: Or a 1x3 beside a 1x1 in the middle; also a loss of structure, but perhaps between the two alternatives, one will work.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that there are simple solutions as well :) Of course, there are several other possible combinations, like a 2x1 and two 1x1s, or just four 1x1s.

Comment: 1x3 plate and 1x1 superglued or acetone-bonded in middle might be easier and better looking alteration than cutting 3x3 cross.

Comment: @jpa thanks, great suggestion!

Comment: I think aligning a cut cross piece would be a lot more reliable (because it's already aligned) than aligning a 1x1 glued onto the middle of a 1x3 though.

Comment: @RSchulz the best of both worlds would be to use another piece as guide to properly align the pieces before gluing then :)